# Remove the border of a split-container after re-sizing

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

How can i remove the ugly color of a split container when i try to split.
But in windows operating system there contain more than two panel and no border shows when resize the split container just like the folder browser and the drive separate in two panel.
So how to remove this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOBbR.png

Comment: What in the image would you like to remove?

Comment: Update the image and mark the thing you want to be removed!

Comment: not the separation border,when  I resize the panel then show this border,I remove the border after complete resize but when dragging its not removed so i just wanna say like windows seven my computer screen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this got resolved but I was in a similar situation and set the following properties for the SplitContainer:

```
SplitterWidth = 2
TabStop = False
```

The width of `2` probably gives no space to display the default border of the split separator (the vertical line in your image).